# Splitting numbers into equal parts

Tags: logic, contest-math, self-learning

I am trying to solve a problem in which I am dividing a list stick into equal size given by K.

Input: stick = [5, 9, 7], K = 4

This means that we have three sticks with lengths as 5, 9 and 7. We would like to come up with K=4 equal length sticks by cutting these three sticks. We would like to end up with K=4 equal length sticks.

From the first stick with length 5, we can have one stick with length 4.

From the second stick with length 9, we can have two sticks with length 4.

From the third stick with length 7, we can have one stick with length 4.
For example:

```
Input: stick = [5, 9, 7], K = 4
Output: 4

Explanation:
Cut arr[0] = 5 = 4 + 1
Cut arr[1] = 9 = 2 * 4 + 1
Cut arr[2] = 7 = 4 + 3
```

Example 2:

```
Input: stick[] = {5, 9, 7}, K = 3
Output: 5 \

Explanation:
Cut arr[0] = 5 = 5
Cut arr[1] = 9 = 5 + 4
Cut arr[2] = 5 = 5 + 2
```

Trying to create a logic what is best possible method, how we can divide them into K equal parts.

Comment: It seems like you need to choose the length $L$ as large as possible such that $\sum \lfloor L_i / L \rfloor \ge K$ (where $L_i$ is the length of the $i$-th initial stick).  You can find the largest such $L$ using a bisection search.

Comment: For $K=4$, you can get four sticks of length $4\frac12$ by splitting $5=4\frac12+\frac12$ and $9=4\frac12+4\frac12$ and $7=4\frac12+2\frac12$.  Are you constraining the stick lengths to be integers?

Comment: Yes my focus is only on int which is `4` instead of float

Comment: (The concept of "floating point" doesn't really apply in Math.)

Comment: How you get that answer? Can you please explain the logic ?

Comment: @AHF: You should include either "@ mjqxxxx" or "@ Scott" in your comment to indicate who you are talking to.

Comment: I was asking to @Scott

Comment: @AHF: OK; what are you asking? How I got the $4\frac12$ answer?